# R vs spss: ttest in python with different result after bootstrapping

Tags: python, t-test, sampling, spss, bootstrap

Running paired t-test after bootstrapping results in very different results when using SPSS versus "ttest_rel" function in python. Why is that and which one is correct?

I first had 5-fold cross-validation. To compare pair-wise, each fold was run with two models. That is, for instance, fold k=0 was run with model 1 and model 2. I then measured the mean average precision (MAP). Now I want to compare which model is more accurate. Please note that I am comparing the values for each fold separately in order to prevent the violation of the independence condition for t-test. To summarize, I have now paired scores of ap_x and ap_y, on which I ran t-test with bootstrapping.

Given a sample with pairs of ap_x and ap_y with size n=30, after bootstrapping 10,000 times for pair-wise t-test, the SPSS gives a t-value of about 1.717 and a p-value of .157. SPSS code:

```
BOOTSTRAP
  /SAMPLING METHOD=SIMPLE
  /VARIABLES INPUT=ap_x  ap_y
  /CRITERIA CILEVEL=95 CITYPE=BCA  NSAMPLES=10000
  /MISSING USERMISSING=EXCLUDE.
T-TEST PAIRS=ap_x WITH ap_y (PAIRED)
  /CRITERIA=CI(.9500)
  /MISSING=ANALYSIS.
```

However, doing the same in python using "scipy.stats.ttest_rel" returns t=81.378 with p<.001 and Cohen-d= 1.146. The bootstrapping function is:

```
def func_bootstrapping(n_samples, x, y):

diff_list = []

sample_means_overall_x = []
sample_means_overall_y = []

for _ in range(n_samples):
    sample_mean_x = np.random.choice(x,size=len(x)).mean()
    sample_means_overall_x.append(sample_mean_x)

    sample_mean_y = np.random.choice(y,size=len(y)).mean()
    sample_means_overall_y.append(sample_mean_y)

    diff_list += [sample_mean_x - sample_mean_y]

return sample_means_overall_x, sample_means_overall_y, diff_list
```

The mean difference between two vairables= 0.033.
I first thought it is the sampling effect; however, repeating it several times, returns the same values.

ap_x and ap_y, the repeated measurement of ap variable over different conditions, are for the most part similar, with mean values of 0.968 and 0.934. The two variables have mostly values of 1.0 except a few cases where the value of ap_x is larger than ap_y.

I cannot interpret the results. Can anyone please help with explaining why this happens and which one is the correct response? Are the difference significant or not?

A sample dataset pasted below. However, please note that this issue occures for lots of the conditions (>80) that I tested pairwise. The scores are the results of Mean Average Precision in an offline evaluation. Each row is a user:

```
index,ap_x,ap_y
0,1.0,1.0
1,0.8875,0.679166666666667
2,1.0,1.0
3,1.0,1.0
4,1.0,1.0
5,1.0,1.0
6,1.0,1.0
7,1.0,1.0
8,1.0,1.0
9,1.0,1.0
10,1.0,1.0
11,1.0,1.0
12,1.0,1.0
13,1.0,1.0
14,1.0,1.0
15,0.5,0.0
16,0.833333333333333,0.804166666666667
17,1.0,1.0
18,1.0,1.0
19,1.0,1.0
20,1.0,1.0
21,1.0,1.0
22,1.0,1.0
23,1.0,1.0
24,1.0,1.0
25,1.0,1.0
26,1.0,1.0
27,0.805555555555555,0.5333333333333329
28,1.0,1.0
29,1.0,1.0
```

Comment: What exactly did you do in SPSS? Are you sure SPSS uses the same algorithm as you? For example, when doing permutation testing you would usually permute the group labels rather than do the within-group resampling, another way to do this is to randomly resample all the rows of the data, so group sizes could differ, etc. If you're not using same procedure, results do not have to be close.

Comment: I added the SPSS code.  How can I assure that the sampling algorithms in SPSS are the same as my python version? As far as I know for paired t-test bootstrapping is implemented as an option in SPSS.  Another question, how can I assure that which one is correct? Can I report and rely on my python implementation?

Comment: SPSS has pretty detailed documentation https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-spss-statistics-27-documentation#en , if you want to replicate its results, you need to first check what exactly it does. In your SPSS syntax you pass the variables as VARIABLES and do simple bootstrap, so most likely you sample *rows* of your data, so the same $x_i$ is always sampled together with same $y_i$, this would underestimate the variability, but I haven't use SPSS for maybe 10 years so don't trust me on that.

Comment: The  SPSS documentation states:  "The Simple method is case re-sampling with replacement from the original dataset." If I want to do the same in python, how can I do it for comparison purposes?

Comment: Concatenate `x` and `y` and sample rows.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I didn't get it.

Comment: Sample rows of your data files with replacement. But this is not the best way to do this, as mentioned above. It would be better if you edited the question and told us what exactly are you trying to achieve? It sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: But isn't it what the python script I put does? I have compared two models, calculated the mean average precision for the performance of the models, and I want to see if model x is better than y statistically.

Comment: You appear to be conducting two different tests, so the results aren't comparable.  (SPSS runs a paired t-test while the Python code looks like an unpaired test.)

Comment: As I mentioned above, for python I use "ttest_rel(data1, data2)" which is a paired t-test. The code above is just for bootstrapping.

Comment: But you resample x & y independently, so you destroy all the information about pairing.

Comment: Not really. I had a cross-validation with 5 folds. X and Y are the results of applying model 1 and model 2 on exactly the same fold, e.g., fold k = 0, and I ran them at the same time. Therefore, they are built on exactly the same split of data. Therefore, the only difference between x and y are the underlying model used to generate the outcome, measured using the mean average precision (MAP). As a result, I think x and y are paired. For each row, I have the respective user_id as the index [0:29] in the data above.

Comment: Your code above resamples them independently. Moreover, if you want to compare model performance, you don’t need t-test, nor bootstrap, especially you don’t need to calculate it twice using SPSS & Python, so what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I have two algorithms that I used and want to compare their accuracy and finds out which one is better than the other.   By resampling, do you mean that I should have resampled only the differences instead of what I have above? That is "sample_mean_diff = np.random.choice((x-y),size=len(x-y)).mean()"?